# Algorithms for General Form Consensus

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the optimization problem (see [Boyd et al.](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) Section 7.2):
\begin{align}
& \min_{x_1,\dots,x_N,z}\sum_{i\in[N]} f_i(x_i) \\ 
& \text{subject to } x_i = \tilde{z}_i, \forall i\in[N].
\end{align}
In this reference the authors apply ADMM to solve the problem distributedly.

Do you know any other algorithm that can be applied to solve this problem in a distributed manner?

Comment: In my humble opinion, "distributed" is sometimes overloaded, which is also referred to as "decentralized". For distributed, I would assume you refer to a system with many workers and a single master.

Comment: To answer your question, there are many algorithms besides sophisticated ADMM. You can use classical gradient descent for instance -- assuming $\{f_i\}$ is differentiable.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant @user550103. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look into this https://large-scale-book.mathopt.com/LSCOMO.pdf -- see Chapter 11.